# Why does bash keep adding a leading whitespace to the variable?

Tags: bash, variables

```
var="               bar" (the whitespace is intentional)

echo foo${var}
```

produces

```
foo bar ("var" has leading whitespace)
```

but

```
echo ${var}
```

produces

```
bar ("var" has no leading whitespace)
```

Why? Is this a bug in bash 4.2.37(2)?

Comment: Quotes quotes quotes: `echo "foo${var}"`

Comment: Excuse me, but what does it have to do with quotes... it's even worse with them:

`echo "foo${var}"` produces:
`foo               bar` (retains all the leading whitespace in var, I cannot show that here, since stackoverflow seems to trim the whitespace)

Comment: Of course all the whitespace is preserved when you quote the expansion; what are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you issue `echo` command each of strings you put after it is treated as an "argument". Then `echo` is echoing all its "arguments", delimited by whitespace.
So `echo foo${var}` is first expanded by your shell to:
`echo foo               bar` and then outputed as `foo` and `bar` delimited by single whitespace.
The same with `echo ${var}` which is xpanded to:
`echo                bar` and the produces just `bar`.
Try it "by hand". The results will be the same.
If you would like to "save" spaces use double quotes. `echo "foo${var}"` will be expanded to:
`echo "foo               bar"` and echoed in this exact form.

Comment: Why is that the following code:<br/>
<br/>
`var1="foo"  
var2="bar"  
  
echo im${var1}${var2}`  
  
produces:  
  
`imfoobar`  
  
Notice, no whitespace between arguments added. Why, after all, they are seperate `echo` arguments, aren't they?  
  
But if I add a whitespace to:  
  
`var1="foo           "`  
  
It gets trimmed to `foo `.

Comment: @user5811974: Your ` echo im${var1}${var2}` expands to `echo imfoobar`. That's why. If you set `var1` to `"foo "` it expands to `echo imfoo bar`

Comment: That's why I've asked the question - to understand _why_ it expands the way it does. Shouldn't it expand to `im foo bar`? After all, @chepner wrote **The leading space is what echo outputs between its arguments.** So,  `echo im${var1}${var2}` should produce `im foo bar` and not `imfoobar` ?

Comment: @user5811974: `var1` and `var2` are expanded **exactly** as what they were set. So if `var1`'s value has spaces it will be expanded with spaces. And at the end all subsequent spaces will be 'compressed' to one.

Comment: I understand now. Bash compresses subsequent whitespace and leave just a single space character, unless quoted. And `echo ${var}` produced no whitespace, because it was the only argument and equated to typing `echo [15x space]              bar` which removes all the leading whitespace. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Unquoted whitespace is removed by word-splitting after parameter (variable) expansion. The leading space is what `echo` outputs between its arguments.

Your first example,

```
echo foo${var}
```

results in the strings `foo` and `bar` separated by a large amount of whitespace, which `bash` only uses to treat the two strings as separate arguments, which `echo` outputs separated by a single space. Your second example,

```
echo ${var}
```

presents `echo` with a single argument, `bar`, with a large amount of whitespace separating the command and the argument.

Quoting the parameter expansions in each case preserves all the whitespace in the parameter value.

```
$ var="               bar"
$ echo "foo${var}"
foo               bar
$ echo "${var}"
               bar
```